# SemaphoreSlim - Correct handling of Wait and Release and CancellationToken

Tags: c#, semaphore, cancellation-token

I have code like this:

```
using var semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
...
//doing stuff resulting in multiple calls to this code from several threads:

try
{
  // depending on sync or async context, use one of them:
  semaphoreSlim.Wait(cancellationToken);
  await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
  ...
}
finally
{
  semaphoreSlim.Release();

  // or use catch and ignore bad pattern:
  // ReSharper disable once EmptyGeneralCatchClause
  try { semaphore.Release(); } catch { }
}
```

So when the cancellationToken triggers, there is no successful Wait()-Call on the semaphore counting its internal counter and so the Release()-call will fail.
empty try/catch-bad pattern is not what I want.
Checking cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested may be a race, so don't do this either.

What is the best way to go?

Comment: The Wait method returns true if the current thread successfully entered the SemaphoreSlim; otherwise, false. You should use that to choose if you have to release or not.

Comment: @Alberto only the timeout versions do that

Comment: Have a look at [`Nito.AsyncEx`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) from @StephenCleary that supports `LockAsync()`. Usage: `using var lockHandle = await semaphoreSlim.LockAsync(cancellationToken);` without any `try...finally` blocks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using a timeout, then just move the `Wait` / `WaitAsync` **outside** (before) the `try` block.

If you are using a timeout, then it is fine where it is, but you'll need a `bool` local to track whether you got it or not, then only release in the `finally` if you did in fact take it.

Comment: Not sure if this is really a solution. This will not distinguish if the semaphore-counter got counted or not. This may happen if the cancellationToken triggers. So releasing too often may occur. And no, there is void-return for this vairiant. Maybe using the timeout-variant with an infinite timeout and checking the bool-return value may help.

Comment: @user2290269 If the `cancellationToken` triggers it should throw an `OperationCancelledException` without changing the semaphoe-counter. If you put `Wait` outside  the `try` block you'll never reach `finally` and that's why the counter is not decremented accidentally.

Comment: *"If you are using a timeout, then it is fine where it is,"* -- What's the problem of moving invariably the `Wait`/`WaitAsync` before the `try`, either with or without timeout?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it won't cause a problem; and indeed, you'd need to declare `bool lockTaken = false;` *before* the `try`, and then `lockTaken = [await] lock.Wait[Async]();` *inside*, so: if you prefer it outside: sure, no problem - it'll save a line of code too

Comment: I prefer to do always the waiting before entering the `try`/`finally`, because I consider it the standard pattern of using the `SemaphoreSlim`. Also because it is a future-proof pattern, in case I decide to add cancellation in the future.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I guess I always think in terms of the pattern used by `lock`: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABAzAAgwJhwGEcBvAWACgcadYBDAEwgDsAbATxwmACsYwAFxwB9AM4cWYADIQwAaxwBeHCxgB3ABQBKANxVaOAJYthIyAFdTMKPuq1sx0zgCyOg7Qr3DNNnPma4pIy/toePmSGAPRROAC29CwW9GycxnEADmwwcTDWjE6CNn4K4REOAOw4ANTV5hBWRbZlhgC+Ze2UrUA=

Comment: Yep, the pattern of using the `Monitor` is different. The `Monitor` was designed to be able to survive a `ThreadAbortException` event, without deadlocking. AFAIK the `SemaphoreSlim` has no such ambitions. In case the current thread is aborted during a `Wait`/`WaitAsync` call, all hell is allowed to break loose.